# adding parameter to parent node on mvcsitemap

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a breadcrumb that looks like this

```
Home / Item /
```

where details url receives the item id `http://server/Item/Id`

from there, you can navigate to an Export page wich receives the same Id
of the Details

```
Home / Item / Export
```

which has an url:

`http://server/Item/Export/Id`

Now, on the exprot breadcrumb, the Export link is generated with the item Id.
What I need to do, is on the Export breadcrumb, have the Id set on the Item url,
so I can go to the Item Details page from the Export page.

I'm using mvcsitemap with XML configuration, but can add tags to code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve the route parameter "id" from the current request by setting `preservedRouteParameters="id"` on the nodes that you want to add the Id value to. Read [Routing Basics](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics) to fully understand how this works.